# pre fill symfony2 form using createFormBuilder()

Tags: php, symfony

Here is my form:

```
$studentObj = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectEntityBundle:Student')
                    ->findBy(array('user' => $userId));
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($studentObj)
            ->add('fname', 'text', array('label' => 'First Name'))
            ->add('lname', 'text', array('label' => 'Last Name'))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save My Profile'))
            ->getForm();
```

I pass $userId from route variable. But it does not pre fill the data. How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the "prefill" at controller "level".

Say that you have an `editStudentController` and that your form is named `studentFormType` you will do

```
public function editStudentController() {
  //retrieve here $userId;
  $student = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectEntityBundle:Student')
                                     ->findOneBy(array('user'=>$userId));
  $form = $this->createForm(new studentFormType(), $student);
  [...]
  $view = $form->createView();
  [...]
}
```

Comment: issue was 'findBy'. Had to use findOneBy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the best way is create a FormType for your Entity `ProjectEntityBundle:Student`, can help you with the command

```
$ php app/console doctrine:create:form ProjectEntityBundle:Student
```

you can check and customize the class on `src/ProjectEntityBundle/Form/StudentType.php` and later in your action can use like;

```
// here you can use [ParamConvert][1] to get the correct Entity without call your repository   
public function editStudentAction(Student $student)
{
  // don't forget the 'use' statement on top
  $editForm = $this->createForm(new StudentType(), $student);

  return array('edit_form' => $editForm->createView());
}
```

### Help links

- [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)